# Parsing input expression form console in java

Tags: java, parsing, token

### Heading

I ve read about compilers tree intrepreters and i m stacked to one question how can i parse input expressions in java please some help for inctance imagine we need to parse math expression how can i identify every symbol or token for these operators *,-,+,/ i ll be preciated

Comment: if you could write please write an example code

Answer (score 2):

For simply scanning input, take a look at the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. For something more elaborated, a parser generator like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) might be in order.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of links in the internet about building math parsers.

E.g. http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Teaching/Resources/COMS30122/java/calc/index.html